# How to sent a mail in php with 2 csv attatchments,

Tags: php

How can i send a mail in php with  two attachment.

And the attachments are csv files

Can any one give a simple sample code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/07/22/sending-email-with-multiple-attachments-with-php/

```
<?php

// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
$files = array("file_1.ext","file_2.ext","file_3.ext",......);

// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$from = "mail@mail.com"; 
$subject ="My subject"; 
$message = "My message";
$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
$file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
$data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marek Sebera.Thatas what iam searching for.Thank you once again

Comment: better to vote up and mark as answered than this thanks-comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest you to use a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). It's much easer and secure.

Example:

PHPMailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = $from;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
$mail->AddAddress($to, $toName);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from, $fromName);
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->AddAttachment($pathtofile);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $bodyHTML;
$mail->Send();
```

Zend_Mail

(See the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)